# c# properties\Resource.Designer.cs could not found

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

i am new in c# i  delete i one file from resource now the project not run it show error

[image]

the error is source file 'properties\Resource.Designer.cs' could not be found

now what i need to do

Comment: Did you run custom tool as mentioned in the warning there?

Answer (score 1):

Run the mentionned Custom Tool. If it doesn't work, recreate a new project and add a copy of your created source files.

Tip for apocalypse defusing : save your work (Workspace or source files), or use a version control such as Git.

Answer (score 0):

Double click on warning >> press yes button.

This worked for me on VS2012